# Hearing Loshon Hara from a Gentile

Tags: halacha, loshon-hara, contemporary-halacha

Can a **Gentile** tell me Loshon Hara about another Jew?

Comment: Don't think it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the information being listened to is directly relevant to you (e.g., to arrange a business deal or a marriage), this is prohibited. The Chofetz Chaim ([6:2](https://torah.org/learning/halashon-chapter6/)) makes no difference between a Jew and a Gentile

> **Even merely listening to Lashon Hara is a violation of the Torah**, even
>   if the listener intends not to believe anything while he is listening.
>   Simply bending his ear to hear constitutes a violation.

The reference is to the listening, not to who speaks.

Comment: But regarding lifne iver, maybe there is not lifne Iver when you listen loshon horo from a gentile